# Fira Mono is oblique not upright by default

Tags: xetex, luatex, miktex, fontspec, typewriter

I'm trying to use Fira Mono as my monospaced font, but when I compile my MWE (below) in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the font ends up in its *oblique* variant. What should I be doing differently?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\begin{document}
  \ttfamily
  This should be regular, but is sadly oblique.
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Result]

And the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.6.5)  5 JUN 2020 11:31
entering extended mode
**"C:/Users/User/Dropbox/Work/Stockholms universitet/Uppsatser/Hyresregleringen
/docs/MWE.tex"

("C:/Users/User/Dropbox/Work/Stockholms universitet/Uppsatser/Hyresregleringen/
docs/MWE.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fira\FiraMono.sty"
Package: FiraMono 2019/10/10 (Bob Tennent and autoinst) Style file for Fira Mon
o fonts.

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
"
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 ("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.st
y"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.t
ex"
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.
tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.te
x"))
\XKV@depth=\count171
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.s
ty"
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\x
parse.sty"
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2020-03-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend
-xdvipdfmx.def"
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-02-23 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count172
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count173
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count174
))
Package: xparse 2020-03-06 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count175
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count176
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count177
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count178
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-x
etex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count187
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count188
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count189
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.c
fg")))
Requested font "[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT" at 9.99997pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Regular.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Regular.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.000
03pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Regular.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003p
t
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Bold.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Oblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.000
03pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10
.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FiraMono(0)' created for font 'FiraMono'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures = TeX,HyphenChar=None,Scale =
(fontspec)             1,Extension =
(fontspec)             .otf,WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=
WordSpace,Numbers
(fontspec)             = {Monospaced,OldStyle},UprightFont =
(fontspec)             *-Regular,ItalicFont = *-Oblique,BoldFont =
(fontspec)             *-Bold,BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dfl
t;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Oblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;langu
age=dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FiraMono(1)' created for font 'FiraMono'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures = TeX,HyphenChar=None,Scale =
(fontspec)             1,Extension = .otf,Numbers =
(fontspec)             {Monospaced,OldStyle},UprightFont =
(fontspec)             *-Regular,ItalicFont = *-Oblique,BoldFont =
(fontspec)             *-Bold,BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dfl
t;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Oblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;langu
age=dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FiraMono(2)' created for font 'FiraMono'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures = TeX,HyphenChar=None,Scale =
(fontspec)             1,Extension = .otf,Numbers =
(fontspec)             {Monospaced,Tabular},UprightFont = *-Regular,ItalicFont
(fontspec)             = *-Oblique,BoldFont = *-Bold,BoldItalicFont =
(fontspec)             *-BoldOblique].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Regular.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dfl
t;+tnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Oblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;langu
age=dflt;+tnum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

Requested font "[FiraMono-Medium.otf]/OT" at 9.99997pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Medium.otf]/OT" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "[FiraMono-Medium.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.0000
3pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FiraMono(3)' created for font 'FiraMono'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures = TeX,HyphenChar=None,Scale =
(fontspec)             1,Extension = .otf,Numbers =
(fontspec)             {Monospaced,OldStyle},UprightFont = *-Medium,ItalicFont
(fontspec)             = *-Oblique,BoldFont = *-Bold,BoldItalicFont =
(fontspec)             *-BoldOblique].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Medium.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=d
flt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Bold.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dfl
t;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-Oblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=
dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->s*[1]"[FiraMono-BoldOblique.otf]/OT:script=latn;langu
age=dflt;+tnum;+onum;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

)
Requested font "Fira Mono" at 9.99997pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/OT" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/I/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Fira Mono/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

Requested font "Fira Mono/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf
Requested font "Fira Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Medium.otf

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'FiraMono(4)' created for font 'Fira Mono'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=Word
Space].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
(fontspec)             Mono/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
(fontspec)             Mono/B/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Fira
(fontspec)             Mono/BI/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

 (MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.

("C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/FiraMono(4)/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/FiraMono(4)/b/n on input line 5.
Requested font "Fira Mono/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/fira/
FiraMono-Oblique.otf

[1

] (MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3538 strings out of 414190
 109359 string characters out of 2897541
 405352 words of memory out of 3000000
 21056 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532482 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 61i,4n,107p,336b,266s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: I just noticed that if I don't `\setmonofont`, then everything seems to work just fine. But I should `\setmonofont`, right...? :-/

Comment: No you don't need the \setmonofont{Fira Mono} instruction. The package will do the setup. For me `\setmonofont{Fira Mono}` works but setting a font by font name (`Fira Mono`) can fail - the engines have to do some guessing and depending of a lot of factors they sometimes get it wrong. The package uses therefore file names - that is safer.

Comment: With an up-to-date  TL2020 I cannot see the problem ... However, this should be enough: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\begin{document}
  \ttfamily
  This should be regular, but is sadly oblique.
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike rightly pointed out in her comment, the [documentation](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) to `fontspec` suggests to use filenames instead of font names. The MWE would then be something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraMono}
\begin{document}
  \ttfamily
  This should be regular, but is sadly oblique.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrong autodetection was caused by some incorrect metadata in the fontfiles which has been corrected in package version 4.3 released 2020-06-05. So now you can fix this by just updating your TeXLive distribution. After updating, update the luaotfload cache to ensure that LuaTeX picks up the modified font: Run `luaotfload-tool -u`. Then the auto-detection should pick the right font.

Comment: This is probably useful for others but did not address my particular problem as I’m using XeTeX and MikTeX.

Comment: On MikTeX you also should be able to install updates. I'm not sure right now if XeTeX on Windows requires a cache to be updates, but I would think that MikTeX would handle that automatically.